# mysql select counts by if else condition

Tags: mysql, if-statement

i have a table  named cq500_all(to record diffrent doctor feedback)
now i want know counts when condition status is
field dr_1_finish and field dr_2_finish value is all fill 1

and

when field dr_1 different dr_2 (like dr_1=1 and dr_2=0,or dr_1=0 and dr_2=1 )

cause i want to know two doctors feedback counts (when different doctor's feedback on jpg)

for example image show   CQ500-CT-1_36_08.jpg  and CQ500-CT-1_36_09.jpg is match my select counts
it will be two (select counts result) 
how to make the query on mysql?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count as

```
select count(*) as total
from cq500_all
where dr_1_finish = 1 and dr_2_finish = 1 and dr_1 != dr_2
```

You will got result in `total`

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much just the way you've described it:

```
select *
from cq500_all
where dr_1_finish = 1 and dr_2_finish = 1
and dr_1 != dr_2
```

or (if dr_1 or dr_2 might not be just 0 and 1):

```
select *
from cq500_all
where dr_1_finish = 1 and dr_2_finish = 1
and ((dr_1 = 1 and dr_2 = 0) or (dr_1 = 0 and dr_2 = 1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much too !! you are a master guy